# read-only access of Amazon Cloudwatch using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have read-only access to Amazon Cloudwatch. I have aws_access_key_id, and aws_secret_access_key in terms of credentials. I tried running the code below, but it is throwing an AccessDenied error. What did I do wrong? Also, what services or methods I can explore with read-only access to Amazon Cloudwatch?
Code:

```
import boto3

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
# List alarms of insufficient data through the pagination interface
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
for response in paginator.paginate(StateValue='INSUFFICIENT_DATA'):
    print(response['MetricAlarms'])
```

Error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeAlarms operation: User: arn:aws:iam::996323886532:user/XxxXx is not authorized to perform: cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms on resource: arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-central-1:996323886532:alarm:* because no identity-based policy allows the cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms action
```

Comment: its good practice to always mask your aws account no.

Comment: The error message itself tells you the solution. The action cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms is not in your permissions.

Comment: @SangamBelose I used a dummy aws account no. here

Comment: @SangamBelose, I know it is giving me AccessDenied error, I want to know what else methods I have that I can use to explore with read-only access of the Cloudwatch using boto3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory. You dont have `cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms` permission in your attached policy.

Regarding what actions you can perform, if you are using the managed policy [cloudwatch read-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess.html), check the respective permission listed in this link.

For.e.g the aws cloudwatch readOnly policy has `cloudwatch:List*"` so you can perform `ListMetrics` or `ListMetricStreams`.

If you are using a custom policy / Role, You can check the permissions in your IAM section of your account.